# Json-server not storing fields properly

Tags: reactjs, json-server

I am playing with some react code and trying out json-server.
I wrote this code to have some simple logic to create notes with titles and store it in db. To mimic rest api I used json-server. But something doesn't work for me. When I post a new note through curl or httpie it works. But when I use this form in my app below, it adds the new note but the note is empty (it has only id), without content and title. What am I missing here?

The code is:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function () {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('title');
    const [content, setContent] = useState('content here');
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

    let handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            let res = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/notes", {
                method: "post",
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    title: title,
                    content: content,
                })
            })
            let resJson = await res.json();
            console.log(resJson);
            if (res.status == 201) {
                setTitle('')
                setContent('')
            } else {
                setErrorMessage(`something went wrong, ${res.status}`)
            }
        } catch(err) { 
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="flex flex-col">
                <input 
                type="text" 
                value={title}
                onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)}
                className="border-2 border-gray"/>
                <textarea
                    className="border-2 border-gray"
                    value={content}
                    onChange={(event) => setContent(event.target.value)}
                    autoFocus rows={5} wrap="soft"/>
                <button type="submit">Add</button>
                {errorMessage && <p>{errorMessage}</p>}
            </div>
        </form>
    );
}
```

I run json-server like this:

```
json-server --watch db.json --port 3001
```

The curl (http) command works fine:

```
http post localhost:3001/notes --raw '{ "title": "A", "content": "B" }'
```

Or:

```
http post localhost:3001/notes title="test" content="test content"
```

Because when I display all notes I can see the content sent there:

```
http localhost:3001/notes
```

```
[
    {
        "content": "test content",
        "id": 11,
        "title": "test"
    },
    {
        "content": "B",
        "id": 15,
        "title": "A"
    }
]
```

But when I use my app, all that is added to the db is:

```
{
    "id": 16
}
```

What is missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are missing the `headers` in your fetch request, which is necessary to specify the content type of the data you're sending. You need to set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` for the server to correctly understand the request payload.

```
let res = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/notes", {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        title: title,
        content: content,
    })
})
```